# Filter posts in Wordpress based on conditional parameters

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

The entire front-end, and passing the selected categories from menu to the back-end is working.

Using the parameters (categories id) as filter is not working.

Each item in the table displayed is a category. The results are posts.

```
// cats brand |  cats type     |  cats can not be
//----------------------------------------
//  1 dell    | 15 pc          |  40 broken 
//  2 ibm     | 16 smartphone  |  41 used 
//  3 samsung | 17 monitor     |  42 remanufactured
//  4 hp      | 18 printer
```

What I need to return is this example working:

-> Posts from categories dell or hp

-> also belonging to category pc or monitor

-> are not in broken category

```
$args = array(                   
   'category_name' => 'dell,hp',
   'category__in' => '15,17', 
   'category__not_in' => '40' 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  
    echo "--------------------<br>";
    echo "<br>" . the_title();
    echo "<br>" . the_category();
    endwhile; 
          else:
        ?>
        <p>no results found.</p>
        <?php
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```html
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$cat = ( isset( $_GET['category_select'] ) ) ? $_GET['category_select'] : 1;
$args = array (
    'cat'            => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  
    echo "--------------------<br>";
    echo "<br>" . the_title();
    echo "<br>" . the_category();
    endwhile; 
          else:
        ?>
        <p>no results found.</p>
        <?php
        endif; 
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Thank you Priyanka, but the question is not about return data with WP_Query... It is about combine the correct args and conditionals.